# Subsonic 3.0.0.4 Generates Compiler Errors

Tags: subsonic3

I am using the latest ActiveRecord template files and have generated my classes. However I am getting this error in my Context1.cs class ...

'SubSonic.Schema.IColumn' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of type 'SubSonic.Schema.IColumn' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Like most people I eventually answer my own question by using the very latest build from https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest build from https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0